# What is BIOS in Android

Tags: android, bios

In PC machines, we have BIOS to identify hardware like audio, CPU, HDD, etc. but in Android devices, what is the replacement of BIOS, as we just have Kernel, ROM and ClockWorkMod.

So the BIOS is embedded in kernel, or something else?

Comment: the BIOS is stored in PROM memory in the motherboard of your PC. I think android (and most mobile devices) stores their original OS in some ROM and restore it if we need to and there is no such thing as BIOS.

Comment: Here's a link you might enjoy: [elinux.org - Android Booting](http://elinux.org/Android_Booting). And yes, I think it's kind of embedded in the kernel (+ generic drivers)